# ASP.NET webparts with Oracle 10g

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, web-parts

Hi I would like to use webparts in ASP.NET  website . Is there any support of webparts with Oracle 10g in ASP.NET.

I am new in webparts. I don't know whether there is any provider available for Oracle.

Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do with your Webpart. I'm not sure if you'll find anything pre-built out there.

If you're building your own, there's definitely nothing stopping you from using ADO.NET to connect to an Oracle database to pull back data and render it in your Web Part.

Comment: Hi,
Actually i would like to save user's dashboard information (as a wab part) in database; so that when user loggedin next time, the saved settings of dashboard would appears to them.

If we did same with SQLServer; then the database tables for webparts are automatically created when we add sqlprovider.

In case of Oracle , i don't know how it would happens.
Please help

Comment: Are you talking about Web Parts in Sharepoint, or generic ASP.NET Web Parts?

Comment: Web parts in ASP.NET ONLY for personalization of dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The current Oracle ODBC driver conforms to the ODBC 3.51 specifications

So you can use it as an ODBC Data source for your web parts.